# Select each new A element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a page where images are loaded automatically. These pictures are included in the element `<a>`. I need to find and remove all elements `<a>`, except those that contain the class `.private_overlay`. I created for this very simple piece of code:

```
$('#content a').not($('a').find('div.private_overlay').parent()).remove();
```

It works when I run it manually. But it doesn't work on elements that are loaded when I run the script.

I tried to loop this way:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#content a').not($('a').find('div.private_overlay').parent()).remove();
});
```

It works, in a way. But this is not what I expect. This script is to be run by one click.

[image]

I just want to apply to work on the new items on this page:

[image]

There are a lot of blocks with posts. I am looking for posts marked as private. To this end, I must to hide all untagged posts, including those that have not yet loaded.

That's how it looks and works at the moment:

[image]

I need to know how to select the new elements as it is to me still needed to find the next or previous image.

I pasted below the code:

```
function searchBox() {
  $('body').append('<div id="searchBox"><p style="margin: 0px;"><strong>Wyszukiwarka prywatnych postów:</strong></p>    \
<p style="margin: 5px auto; text-align: center"><input id="previousPost" type="button" value="Poprzedni post"></input>  \
<input id="nextPost" type="button" value="Następny post"></input></p>   \
<p style="margin: 0px;"><input id="hidePosts" type="checkbox"></input><label for="hidePosts" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Kasuj niepotrzebne posty</label></p></div>');

  $('#searchBox').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    left: '20px',
    bottom: '20px',
    background: 'white',
    color: 'rgb(125, 125, 125)',
    fontSize: '13px',
    border: '1px solid rgb(125, 125, 125)',
    borderRadius: '7px',
    padding: '7px',
    zIndex: '9999',
    boxShadow: '0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    display: 'none'
  }).fadeIn();

  $('#hidePosts').one('click', function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      $('#content a').not($('a').find('div.private_overlay').parent()).remove();
    });
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
  });

  $('#previousPost').click(function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $("#content a").prev().offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });

  $('#nextPost').click(function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $("#content a").next().offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
};
```

I tried to understand [this article](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) but I do not understand.

Comment: +1 for images... lmao

Comment: If it works in a scroll event handler, it surely works in a click event handler as well ?

Comment: So new images are loaded (inside of `<a>` elements) and, once they're loaded/appended to the page, you want want to remove those `<a>` elements without the `private_overlay` class?

Comment: Hmm, yes, I want remove all, but no "private_overlay". Later I must find only this "private_overlay" and jump between them.

Comment: What browser compatibility do you require? Note, if it includes any IE less than 10 you're probably looking at a `window.setInterval()`-based solution.

Comment: You should hook into the code that appends the images, and check if the checkbox is checked, and then determine wether or not to output the anchors, not remove them after they are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, via conversation in comments, you want all instances of `<a>` that don't have the class `private_overlay` to be removed instantly, when the user clicks a button. So, first, the removal code can be simplified.

```
$('#content a').not('a.private_overlay').remove();
```

Second ... all we need to do is call this action when the user clicks a button.

```
$('button#remove').click(function() {

    $('#content a').not('a.private_overlay').remove();

});
```

This will work even on dynamically inserted content, as shown by the Fiddle.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A39MV/5/)

Comment: Oh God why, what's the difference? You can't delegate the scroll event on the window!

Comment: My code to hide works. Not only works on the new elements that page loads later. I can not give you this site with "private_overlay" because only I have access to it. But I can give you very similar: http://blog.isvn.pl/archive There is no "private_overlay", but you can see how working load.

Comment: Nice, with .on('scroll') working properly, but... only when I scroll.

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding what you are asking. Do you want the items to be removed as the user scrolls, or when the button is clicked?

Comment: If you click the button, then you need to use setInvertal, right? Because this button, you can click only once.

Comment: Do you want the button click to instantly remove all the `<a>` that don't have that class?

Comment: You do not need `.scroll` or setInterval. Just need to have jQuery remove all instances on the click. I'll update my Fiddle.

Comment: No, because when you delete posts by clicking. And what of new posts that appear when scrolling page? Then again, you have to press a button. Even better solution is this that run the script while scrolling.

Comment: And still do not know how to find posts from this class. These and new posts. In the code I have two buttons: one to jump to the previous post and one to jump to the next post. It uses function animate () and scrollTop. This works, but only for the first few posts. The script does not see any posts that are loaded later - by another script.

Comment: ... You told me that you wanted the button, not scrolling click to remove all `<a>`. My answer had the code to remove when scrolling.